# Remove a UITextField from a view

Tags: iphone, objective-c

how can I remove a UITextField from a View? I've assigned a tag to the UITextfield and I search it from the subviews in the main view. But when I found it, it do a strange thing: doesn't execute the after instruction, or exactly it execute the instruction, but do nothing. Instead if I hidden it, all works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Why won't you use removeFromSuperview selector?

Comment: Like [nametextField removeFromSuperview]? It's the same :|

Answer (score 0):

You should by able to completely remove the `UITextField` by calling `- (void)removeFromSuperview` on the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove your views by using `removeFromSuperview`
and should be like ---> [`myTextView removeFromSuperview]`

Comment: @Andrea :Why are you removing it and How ?

Answer (score 0):

I think there might be other views over UITextView.Since

```
[myTextView removeFromSuperview];
```

should work fine.You can remove any of the view which is in SuperView.

So, please make sure that UITextView is still there ....or from somewhere else still textView is allocated & added to subivew.

Either you can set the Different BackGround Colors for TextView so that you can easily trace whether what is removed from SuperView.